# React Prop rendering as object - don't understand why

Tags: object, reactjs, properties, render, state

I'm new to React, and I just can't figure this out...

I'm trying to pass my state to a prop in the parent component, and then render that state in a child component. Like so:

### Parent Component

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         text: 'hello'
      }
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="App">
            <MessageList textProp={this.state.text}/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

### Child Component

```
const MessageList = textProp => {
   return (
   <div className='MessageList'>
      {textProp}
   </div>
   )
}
```

React won't render properly, claiming it is an object that is trying to be rendered.

I can access the property by using `{textProp.textProp}`, why is it rendering an object which contains a property of the same name?

I'm sure this is very simple but I could do with an explanation!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components' props are an object, just as their state is an object. Therefore you want something more like:

```
const MessageList = props => {
   return (
   <div className='MessageList'>
      {props.textProp}
   </div>
   )
}
```

or, using destructuring:

```
const MessageList = ({ textProp }) => {
   return (
   <div className='MessageList'>
      {textProp}
   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfectly explained.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare stateless component you need to specify the arguments you want it to receive it can be `(props)` or `({ specific })` in your case:

```
const MessageList = ({ textProp }) => (
 <div className='MessageList'>
      {textProp}
   </div>
);
```

Note how i do `=> ()` that will return the markup, you don't have do to `{ return () }`  just a tip to run things better :)

Comment: Cheers for the tip! I actually forgot about that extra advantage of arrow functions...

Answer (score 0):

The `textProp` in `MessageList` is a collection of `props` form the parent. In your case the collection will have only `textProp.` To make this work you need to do the following.

```
const MessageList = ( {textProp} ) => {
   return (
   <div className='MessageList'>
      {textProp}
   </div>
   )
}
```

or

```
const MessageList = (textProp) => {
   return (
   <div className='MessageList'>
      {textProp.textProp}
   </div>
   )
}
```